# SQLite Count between two tables

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm not sure if this is possible in SQLite (for an Android app) as it may require and an `INNER JOIN` or `OUTER JOIN` which sqlite doea not support.

I'm trying to output the values of a `JOIN` between two tables that includes the count of fields in one table:

```
[Table1]
ID  Title
1   "Title 1"
2   "Title 2"
3   "Title 3"

[Table2]
ID PID Title      New
1  1   "Title 1a"  0
2  2   "Title 2a"  1
3  2   "Title 2b"  1
4  3   "Title 3a"  0
5  3   "Title 3b"  0

Desired output:
1  0  "Title 1"
2  2  "Title 2"
3  0  "Title 3"
```

What I have:

```
SELECT Table2.pid,count(Table2.pid),Table1.title
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 
ON Table2.pid = Table1.id
WHERE Table2.new = 1
GROUP BY Table2.pid
```

Outputs:

```
2  2  "Title 2"
```

Comment: Please provide the `.dump` (SQLite3 commandline tool) of a tailored toy database which demonstrates the goal, as part of your [mcve].

Comment: Your query has 3 columns in the SELECT. Your desired output has 2. I'm not 100% clear on what it is you really want and I think you should clarify. Aside, INNER JOIN *is* supported by SQLite as is LEFT OUTER JOIN, but not RIGHT OUTER or FULL OUTER.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value you want by aggregation in a subquery:

```
select 
  (select count(*) from Table2 t2 where t2.pid = t1.id and t2.New = 1) counter,
  t1.Title
from
  Table1 t1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nfDHCMhpv5zjx8ev6seQD4/0)
Another solution with group by:

```
select 
  count(t2.Title) counter, 
  t1.Title 
from Table1 t1
left join (
  select * from Table2 where new = 1
) t2
on t2.pid = t1.id
group by t1.Title
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nfDHCMhpv5zjx8ev6seQD4/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a LEFT JOIN in sqlite. Simply change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`. From [the doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

> If the join-operator is a "LEFT JOIN" or "LEFT OUTER JOIN", then after
>   the ON or USING filtering clauses have been applied, an extra row is
>   added to the output for each row in the original left-hand input
>   dataset that corresponds to no rows at all in the composite dataset
>   (if any). The added rows contain NULL values in the columns that would
>   normally contain values copied from the right-hand input dataset.

It will return null when there are no rows in Table2. (Perhaps you could use a `CASE` statement to display 0, but I'm not familiar with the interface).